# Python Django Admin not showing CSS

Tags: python, django

I was working with Django latest version by watching a tutorial on YT, but for some reason, my admin page isn't coming how it has to. It does not have a style or CSS.

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrASY.png`enter code here`

Comment: have you tried `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running in debug or production mode?

Django delivers static files like CSS, JS etc in debug though it's own development server.
When you run in production mode / through a web server you have to configure your web server to deliver the static files.

Cheers

Comment: Right now I am in debug mode as I have just started using it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you should first try this in the command line:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

After that go to settings file and check `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT`

It should look like this(if you didn't change anything):

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/example.com/static/"`

**Static Url:** *URL to use when referring to static files located in STATIC_ROOT.*

**Static Root:**
*The absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect static files for deployment.*

and also you can check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/).

Comment: Are you using Nginx?

Comment: @Aman Sharma check the browsers network monitor. It'll show you which resources are requested and from where.